# Where did this normalisation factor come from?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, fourier-transform

Just wondering where the normalisation factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_{\mathrm{p}}}}$ comes from in this field operator expression?

\begin{equation}
\phi(\mathbf{x})=\int \frac{d^{3} p}{\left(2 \pi^{3}\right)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_{\mathrm{p}}}}\left(a_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}+a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566776/2451 and links therein.

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248279/84967

Comment: my favourite explanation of this normalisation is in Pitaevski snd Lifshits’ quantum electrodynamics volume: turning off interactions, it corresponds to ensuring that a universe with a single particle contains the energy of a single particle.

Answer (score 1):

This also bothered me when I was learning QFT. My current understanding is that this $1\over\sqrt{2\omega_p}$ is not important. The reasons why books are written in this I guess are as following.

1. People used to work with harmonic oscillators, where they set
   $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}(a+a^\dagger).$$
   Remember that QFT is merely many harmonic oscillators with different $\omega$ summed together. So they chose this historical convention.
2. This factor can simplify the commutator of $a$ and $a^\dagger$
   $$[a_{p},a_{p'}^\dagger]=(2\pi)^3\delta^3(p-p').$$
   This makes $a$ and $a^\dagger$ more suitable for the name creation/annihilation operators.

You need not stick to this convention. Some books, for example, string theory textbooks, do not adopt this convention. And you will get a slightly different version of commutators.